Run SQL in Python and assign output values to variables using python
With an SQL query included in a python script, I need to be able to assign each column value (2 columns with only 1 row as an output from query) to a variable like this:
sqlquery = """SELECT MIN(DATE) AS STARTDATE, MAX(DATE) AS ENDDATE
              FROM table"""

cursor.execute(sqlquery)

sqlqueryresult = cursor.fetchall()

sqlqueryresult = list(sqlqueryresult)

STARTDATE, ENDDATE = [sqlqueryresult[i] for i in (0, 1)]

But I'm getting this error: IndexError: list index out of range
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

The query will return a single row consisting of a two-element tuple.(print sqlqueryresult and see what you get)

For a single row you can probably use fetchone. So STARTDATE, ENDDATE = cursor.fetchone()

You're almost there, it just these couple of changes will help you to achieve your results.
sqlquery = """SELECT MIN(DATE) AS STARTDATE, MAX(DATE) AS ENDDATE
              FROM table"""

cursor.execute(sqlquery)

sqlqueryresult = cursor.fetchone()

STARTDATE, ENDDATE = [sqlqueryresult[i] for i in range(0, 2)]

print("STARTDATE = ", STARTDATE)
print("ENDDATE = ", ENDDATE)

